# getboundingclientrect not return same value

Tags: javascript, html, tracker, getboundingclientrect

Im tracking clicks on my website. For each clicks im taking the coordinates of the click on the clicked element ( referenced with the function getPath who return the css path) with the following function:

```js
add_click(event) {
      var element = event.target;
      var dimensions = element.getBoundingClientRect();
      var click = {
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight,
        path: getPath(element),
        x: event.offsetX / dimensions.width,
        y: event.offsetY / dimensions.height,
        key: event.which
      };
      this.clicks.push(click);
    }
```

Then i'm creating visualisation of clicks. For this im reconverting X and Y coordinates of the element into X and Y coordinates of the window. For this im using :

```js
var element = document.querySelector(path); //return the clicked element
var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
var X = rect.left + click["x"] * rect.width;
 var Y = rect.top + click["y"] * rect.height;
```

However getBoundingClientRect() is not returning the same value for an element every time i load page. Value returned from getBoundingClientRect() for a same element keep changing and this creating wrong coordinates for my click.

I have tested it on Chrome 87 and Firefox 78 both are returning different value for getBoundingClientRect() for the same exact window size.

Does anyone know why this is happening, have met this bug before or have another function that is not broken to get coordinates of a DOM element?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: There are lots of things that can affect where an element ends up on a page, chiefly the size of the browser window, the size of content in that element and others, etc. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).